# TypeORM entity relationship doesn't seems to be working

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I've got these 2 entities:

```
@Entity('user_table')
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number; 

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    user_id: string;

    @Column()
    deleted: boolean;

    @Column()
    real_name: string;

    @Column()
    timezone: string;

    @OneToOne(type => UserProfile, userProfile => userProfile.id, { cascade: true }) 
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'profile_id' })
    userProfile: UserProfile;
}
```

```
@Entity('user_profile')
export class UserProfile {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number; 

    @Column()
    status_text: string;

    @Column()
    status_emoji: string;

    @Column()
    image_512: string;
}
```

I'm able to insert the User entity data correctly, but the UserProfile data isn't being added. The foreign key seems to be created, but it's null.

Hope somebody can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that the `userProfile => userProfile.id` part is wrong. This is for you to specify the inverse part if you want to create a bi-directional relation. Read https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/one-to-one-relations.md

Comment: can you share a payoad ?

Comment: @MohsinAmjad I fixed it following the example above and changing a field name, but thank you anyway.